# Algebra of upper triangular matrices

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, solution-verification, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $R$ the algebra of $3\times3$ upper triangular matrices $(a_{ij})$ st $a_{11}=a_{22}=a_{33}$.

1. Find the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ of $R$

**Attempt**: Using the characterization $y\in J(R)\iff 1-xy\in U(R),\ \forall x\in R$ I found that $$J(R)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ a \ b\\ 0\ 0 \ c \\ 0\ 0 \ 0\end{pmatrix}:a,b,c\in k\right\}$$

2. Show that every two simple $R-$modules are isomorphic.

**Attempt**: The left simple $R-$modules coincide with left simple $R/J(R)-$modules and $R/J(R)=k$ which is a simple Artinian ring. Hence all simple $R-$modules are isomorphic.

3. Let $M,N$ two semisimple $R-$modules with $\dim_kM=\dim_kN<\infty$. Is it true that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic?

**Attempt**: Yes. It is $M=V^m,\ N=V^n$ where $V$ is the unique up to isomorphism simple $R-$ module. So $n\dim_kV=\dim_kN=\dim_kM=m\dim_kV<\infty \Rightarrow m=n \Rightarrow M\cong N$.

4. Let $M,N$ be two $R-$modules with $\dim_kM=\dim_kN<\infty$.  Is it true that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic?

**Attempt**: I suppose they are not since $R$ is not a simple algebra ($\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ 0 \ b\\ 0\ 0 \ 0 \\ 0\ 0 \ 0\end{pmatrix}:b\in k\right\}$ is an ideal) but I can't find a counter-example.

> 1. Is my approach correct?

> 2. What about $4$?

> 3. Can you give a general example where $R$ is a $k-$algebra of finite dimension (not simple) and the equivalence $M\cong N\iff \dim_kM=\dim_kN<\infty$ does not hold?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your third question did you mean to write $N=V$ in one way or another?  Because it seems obviously false if you're allowed to pick any $N$ different from $V$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant $N$ not $V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my approach correct?

Yes, your approaches to 1-3 are fine.

> What about 4?

For 4), you already know that you aren't going to have any luck with semisimple modules, so you need to use one that isn't semisimple. Why not start with $R$ itself?

$R$ itself is a $4$-dimensional $k$ algebra, so we'll use that as $M$.

Then just let $N$ be a semisimple module of length $4$ (four copies of the unique simple module.)

Obviously $M\ncong N$, but they have the same $k$-dimension.

> Can you give a general example where $R$ is a $k-$algebra of finite dimension (not simple) and the equivalence $M\cong N\iff \dim_kM=\dim_kN<\infty$ does not hold?

Answering 4) above does that, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For $(4)$ could I use the following? Take $R=\mathbb{C}[S_n]$ and the modules of rank $1$ that correspond to the trivial and sign representation of $S_n$. Then they have the same dimension over $\mathbb{C}$ but are not isomorphic

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου Yes, that would work because the second one is homogeneous semisimple and $R$ is not.